# Tasks with depends_on_past=True are in "None" state because newer task runs are queued ahead of older task runs. Solution?

Tags: airflow

This question is about Airflow 2.5.1, using the Celery executor.

We have a DAG that fits a model and produces a forecast for "today" based on data that was available "yesterday".

Therefore, we define the forecasting Task with `depends_on_past=True`, to ensure that the forecasts are produced in the correct sequence. In addition, due to external resource limits, we set `max_active_tis_per_dag=1`. We are using the default setting of `weight_rule=WeightRule.downstream`.

Consider the following timeline of DAG and Task runs:

1. `t0`: Task succeeds
2. `t1`: Task succeeds
3. `t2`: Task fails
4. `t3`: DAG run active, Task has "no status"
5. `t4`: DAG run active, Task has "no status"

If I clear the failed task at `t2`, the DAG deadlocks here. It appears that the scheduler is prioritizing the `t3` and `t4` task instances more highly than the now-cleared `t2` task instance, but the `t3` task instance is waiting for the `t2` task to complete before it can be scheduled on a worker, so it never gets scheduled and everything ends up stuck.

Through trial and error, we figured out that we can fix this by clearing not only the `t2` task instance but all task instance *after* `t2`, in this case `t3` and `t4`.

This is an annoying situation, and in some cases the dependency graph is a lot more complicated (maybe even including cross-DAG dependencies), so it's not always easy to see when a DAG (or collection of DAGs) is stuck in this state.

I have a few questions related to this situation:

1. Is my assessment of the problem correct? Is the scheduler actually prioritizing the `t3` and `t4` tasks higher than the `t2` task, causing a deadlock? Or is that not how the Airflow scheduler works, and the problem would lie elsewhere?
2. If I wanted to investigate the contents of the scheduler queue, to determine if this is (or is not) actually the problem, how would I do that? I don't see any way to view that in the Airflow UI.
3. Is there a way to set up some kind of detection system for this situation, so that we can be alerted if it occurs? E.g. we can send an email or Slack message saying "Scheduler queue is deadlocked and requires manual intervention."
4. If this is indeed the problem, can something be done to avoid it in the first place? It's easy to fix it once you know what's happening, but it's confusing and alarming to see a row of empty boxes in the Airflow UI grid 0 running task instances and no sign of progress. Could this be avoided by changing `weight_rule` somehow? Can the scheduler be configured to detect this situation and fix it automatically, e.g. re-order its task queue using a topological sort? Are we causing the problem somehow by setting `max_active_tis_per_dag=1`?

Sorry for this being a big multi-part question. Hopefully the 4 parts above can be answered  mostly as yes/no with some links to relevant docs, issue tracker threads, etc. I would be happy with partial answers that at least point me in the right direction.

Note that I am not an Airflow expert, I am taking over a system that was set up by someone else. This question is partly due to my annoyance with this small problem, and partly due to my feeling that I don't understand Airflow very well.